# How to search tweets from an id to another id

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

I'm trying to get tweets using [TwitterSearch](https://github.com/ckoepp/TwitterSearch) in Python3.

So basically I want to get all tweets between these 2 IDs.

`748843914254249984` ->`760065085616250880`

These 2 IDs are from the

`Fri Jul 01 11:41:16 +0000 2016` to `Mon Aug 01 10:50:12 +0000 2016`

So here's the code I made.

`crawl.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python3               
# coding: utf-8                  

from TwitterSearch import *
import datetime

def crawl():
    try:
        tso = TwitterSearchOrder()
        tso.set_keywords(["keyword"])
        tso.set_since_id(748843914254249984)
        tso.set_max_id(760065085616250880)

        ACCESS_TOKEN = xxx
        ACCESS_SECRET = xxx
        CONSUMER_KEY = xxx
        CONSUMER_SECRET = xxx

        ts = TwitterSearch(
            consumer_key = CONSUMER_KEY,
            consumer_secret = CONSUMER_SECRET,
            access_token = ACCESS_TOKEN,
            access_token_secret = ACCESS_SECRET
        )

        for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
            print(tweet['id_str'], '-', tweet['created_at'])

    except TwitterSearchException as e:
        print( e )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    crawl()
```

I'm not very familiar with Twitter API and searching with it. But this code should do the job.

But it's giving :

```
760058064816988160 - Mon Aug 01 10:22:18 +0000 2016
[...]
760065085616250880 - Mon Aug 01 10:50:12 +0000 2016
```

Many, many times... Like I got the same lines over and over again instead of getting everything between my two IDs.

So I'm not getting any of the July tweets, any idea why ?

Comment: Does it work when you remove the `set_since_id` and `set_max_id` settings?

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra Yes, it's getting me 198 tweets of today. From 07:51 to 08:54.

Comment: If I run your code and put a counter in the loop (`i=0;for(): i+=1;if i==300:break;`), it _is_ actually working. But it only finds (exactly) 100 tweets and then restarts the loop. So with `i=300` I get the same results exactly 3 times.

Comment: Uh, that is, Aug tweets. I'm not getting tweets from July.

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra It's depending on the keyword I guess. I use "Vuitton" in my case.

Comment: @NanderSpeerstra I'm not really getting what you mean with the counter in the loop..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Remove the `tso.set_max_id(760065085616250880)` line.

**Explanation (as far as I understand it)**

I have found your problem in the [TwitterSearch Docs](https://twittersearch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_usage_tso.html):

"The only parameter with a default value is count with 100. This is because it is the maximum of tweets returned by this very Twitter API endpoint."

If I check this in your code by creating a search URL, I get:

```
tso.create_search_url()
#?q=Vuitton&since_id=748843914254249984&count=100&max_id=760065085616250880
```

which contains **`count=100`** (meaning it will get the first page of 100 tweets). And, in contrast with removing the `set_since_id` and `set_max_id` which also has `count=100` and retrieves many more tweets, it stops at 100 tweets.

`set_since_id` without `set_max_id` works, the other way around doesn't. So removing the `max_id=760065085616250880` from the search URL resulted in the results you want.

If anyone can explain why `set_max_id` is not working along, please edit my answer.